# Codable and CodingKeys

Tags: swift, codable, decodable, encodable

I'm trying to implement a protocol with similar functionality to how `Codable` uses the `CodingKeys` enum.

With `Codable` and `CodingKeys`, if you don't implement a case in the `CodingKeys` enum for every property on the `Codable` object, it causes a compiler error stating that the object does not conform to the protocol.

I have looked through documentation, and the only thing I can find related to the `Codable` (`Encodable` and `Decodable`) protocol is the requirement to implement the `func encode(to encoder: Encoder)` and `init(from decoder: Decoder)` functions.

The closest I've gotten is defining a protocol as follows:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    associatedType Keys: CodingKey
}
```

This requires the implementer to have a `Keys` property that conforms to `CodingKey`, but it does not enforce the requirement to have a case for all properties. Additionally, you cannot declare the `Keys` property as private like you can with `Codable`.

Are `Codable` and `CodingKeys` handled at a deeper level than what is exposed through the APIs?

If not, is there a way to implement the `CodingKeys` functionality outside of `Codable`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ask two questions. I think it will be easier to explain them in reverse order.

> Are Codable and CodingKeys are handled at a deeper level than what is exposed through the APIs?

Yes, the Swift compiler knows about the `Encodable`, `Decodable`, and `CodingKey` protocols and has special code for them.

The compiler can synthesize a `CodingKey`-compliant `enum` named `CodingKeys`, the `init(from:)` initializer, and the `encode(to:)` method, if some conditions are met. The conditions are spelled out in [SE-0166](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md):

> `Encodable` & `Decodable` requirements can be automatically synthesized for certain types as well:
>
> 1. Types conforming to `Encodable` whose properties are all `Encodable` get an automatically generated `String`-backed `CodingKey` `enum` mapping properties to case names. Similarly for `Decodable` types whose properties are all `Decodable`
> 2. Types falling into (1) — and types which manually provide a `CodingKey` `enum` (named `CodingKeys`, directly, or via a `typealias`) whose cases map 1-to-1 to `Encodable`/`Decodable` properties by name — get automatic synthesis of `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` as appropriate, using those properties and keys
> 3. Types which fall into neither (1) nor (2) will have to provide a custom key type if needed and provide their own `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`, as appropriate

Note that the `CodingKey`-compliant type does not in general *have* to be named `CodingKeys` or even be an `enum` unless you are relying on compiler-synthesized conformance.

Furthermore, note that a `CodingKeys` type conforming to `CodingKey` only needs to have a case for every member of its enclosing type if you are relying on the compiler to synthesize `init(from:)` or `encode(to:)`.

If you're manually implementing `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`, you can use any name for your `CodingKey`-compliant type, and it only has to have the cases you care about. You don't even need a `CodingKey`-compliant type if you're only using a single-value container or an unkeyed container for storage.

> If not, is there a way to implement the CodingKeys functionality outside of Codable?

If, by “functionality”, you mean the way the compiler automatically synthesizes implementations, then the only way is by using a code generator (like Sourcery or gyb) to generate source code and feed it to the compiler.

If, by “functionality”, you mean the way the compiler requires a key member for each `Encodable`/`Decodable` member of the enclosing type, then the only way is by running a separate program that analyzes your source code and errors out if any case is missing. You can't make the standard Swift compiler do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the explanation I was looking for.